# B2B Commerce - PLP Title and Meta Update

Tags: community, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze, b2b

We are using CC (3.147.4)

We have set the storefront Seo Title as "XYZ Company | Retail"

We want to update the Title of the PLP page. Lets say "XYZ Company | Fruits" where fruit is category name. Now i did find any option in salesforce to do the same. Is there a simple way to do this? It pretty common requirement i believe?

**This for our SEO purpose, so updating it via javascript after page load will not work.

Along with this, we also want update meta tags to add the keywords specifically to category page. Is there a way around to this?

Appreciate any kind of a help here.

Comment: Have you gone through the SEO documentation for the B2B Visualforce package: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=b2b_commerce_seo.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly there is no way of assigning category name to page title, you can only set the title in CC Admin for the storefront, but category needs to be added dynamically with JS.